# change icon image of .py file and make it executable

Tags: raspbian

I need to change icon image of .py file to my own image. also it needs to be run as terminal without always asking that from me.

Answer (score 2):

you'll need to add the following at the top of your py file

`#!/usr/bin/python`

and change the file attributes to include execute

`chmod +x myscript.py`

this should allow you to simply (double) click and execute from a GUI based file explorer.

An alternative is to use a tool such as [`pyinstaller`](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to create a binary out from your script

With regards to the icon, AFAIK really depends on the desktop environment you are using